# Getting TypeError while spliting Json data?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have A json data like this:

```
json_data = '{"data":"[{"Date":"3/17/2017","Steam Total":60},{"Date":"3/18/2017","Steam Total":15},{"Date":"3/19/2017","Steam Total":1578},{"Date":"3/20/2017","Steam Total":1604}]", "data_details": "{"data_key":"Steam Total", "given_high":"1500", "given_low":"1000", "running_info": []}"}'

json_input_data = json_data["data"]
json_input_additional_info = json_data["data_details"]
```

I am getting an error:

## TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

I think there is an error in the json data. Can someone Help me on this?

Comment: json_data = '{"data":"[.... in the last quote there is an error, you want to declare an array but instead of that a string has been declared because of that quote

Comment: Yes JSON data format is wrong, it should be :                               
json_data = {"data":[{"Date":"3/17/2017","Steam Total":60},{"Date":"3/18/2017","Steam Total":15},{"Date":"3/19/2017","Steam Total":1578},{"Date":"3/20/2017","Steam Total":1604}], "data_details": {"data_key":"Steam Total", "given_high":"1500", "given_low":"1000", "running_info": []}}   Try any json parser to check json data http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you code has some issues.

1. The code: `json_input_data = json_data["data"]`, the variable `json_data` is not a Json Object,  is a String Object and you try get a string position by string key, for get a Json object from string json use `json` api: [json](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/json.html)
2. You Json string isn't valid, this is a valid version:
   `{"data":[{"Date":"3/17/2017","Steam Total":60},{"Date":"3/18/2017","Steam Total":15},{"Date":"3/19/2017","Steam Total":1578},{"Date":"3/20/2017","Steam Total":1604}], "data_details": {"data_key":"Steam Total", "given_high":"1500", "given_low":"1000", "running_info": []}}`
3. Now, your code works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try parsing your **json_data** to JSON format (with `JSON.parse(json_data)`). Currently it's type is string - which is exactly what your error says.

Comment: If you are fetching this data from a dump file, try strigifying your data before dumping it to the file.
For example: If you are using python to dump to the file, use json.dumps(your_data), and then read it back with json.loads(file_content)

Answer (score 0):

You were right. Your JSON is indeed wrong.

Can you try using this json?

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "Date":"3/17/2017",
         "Steam Total":60
      },
      {  
         "Date":"3/18/2017",
         "Steam Total":15
      },
      {  
         "Date":"3/19/2017",
         "Steam Total":1578
      },
      {  
         "Date":"3/20/2017",
         "Steam Total":1604
      }
   ],
   "data_details":{  
      "data_key":"Steam Total",
      "given_high":"1500",
      "given_low":"1000",
      "running_info":[]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As  [Pongpira Upra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7526791/pongpira-upra) pointed out, your json is not well formed and should be something like this.

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "Date":"3/17/2017",
         "Steam Total":60
      },
      {  
         "Date":"3/18/2017",
         "Steam Total":15
      },
      {  
         "Date":"3/19/2017",
         "Steam Total":1578
      },
      {  
         "Date":"3/20/2017",
         "Steam Total":1604
      }
   ],
   "data_details":{  
      "data_key":"Steam Total",
      "given_high":"1500",
      "given_low":"1000",
      "running_info":[]
   }
}
```

In order to retrieve information you should write

```
json_data[0]["Date"]
```

This would print "3/17/2017"

Answer (score 0):

You declare a string called `json_data` and, well, then it acts like a string. That is what the exception tells you. Like others here tried to say - you *do* also have an error in your data, but the exception you supplied is due to accessing the string as if it was a dictionary. You need to add a missing call to e.g. `json.loads(...)`.